# Update user status for major social networks from Blackberry

Tags: facebook, blackberry, twitter, linkedin-api, myspace

I need to do facebook, twitter integration in my application to share on my wall.

Comment: What mechanism did you use for your iPhone application?  Can't that just be re-used in the blackberry?

Comment: I have used fbconnect for facebook and mgtwitterengine for twitter. So, I can't use in blackberry because those are the native code for iPhone only. So, Can you please provide any reference for linkedin, myspace and orkut integration in iPhone as well as in the blackberry application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the other networks, but RIM has officially sanctioned the open source [Facebook API](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/started/facebook.jsp).

Comment: Thanks for the facebook SDK reference. I have implemented only for the facebook and twitter in the iPhone using fbconnect for facebook and mgtwitterengine for twitter. So, If you know about myspace, linkedin and orkut then please share your idea and any reference if you have for the same.